# ${documentReferrer} is empty when document.referrer is "https://www.google.com/"

Tags: amp-html

Looking through the AMP documentation (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#document-referrer) is appears that the `documentReferrer` variable should reflect the JS `document.referrer`.

While `documentReferrer` appears to report the correct value for other domains (like: www.twitter.com, t.co, linkedin.com, etc.) when the page's `document.referrer` value is "https://www.google.com/" `documentReferrer` is empty. I couldn't find any documentation indicating that the www.google.com domain carried any additional caveats.

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: Based on the documentation I would expect the AMP article's `documentReferrer` to be `"https://www.google.com/"` when that was the referring URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AMP documentation is accurate. There is no exception made for "https://www.google.com/".

It is worth mentioning that some AMP tags (like `<analytics-tag>`) allow you to define custom variables for internal use within the tag. These variables can take precedence over global variables (like `documentReferrer`) within that tag's scope.

For more details on one very specific scenario where that can occur see: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10374